# How to use Strapi for cms part only in the existing node.js project?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, strapi

I have an existing project in MERN, now I want only the CMS part in the backend to be done using Strapi.js, rest authentication and other functionalities are already done using node and express. Now, is it possible that in the admin dashboard of my node project, I create a "CMS" button and on clicking it, it redirects to the Strapi admin dashboard without any authentication as the admin is already logged in?
Or am I doing it wrong? Is there any easy alternative of doing this?